# Create a custom view in android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, custom-view

I am new to complicated views in Android, and I'm trying to create this type of view:
example 1[image]
example 2[image]

After looking around, I discovered it can be done using HTML, and CSS. However, I want to know how I can create those views in native Android without using webview?

Edit: Based on the responses I researched and found Lottie's file which can be used to create example 2 UI. So, it creates a JSON file which can later be displayed in the UI. However, the problem is that the alignment of the power flow line and the circle does not align properly. Because the power flow line(Lottie file) when in XML, the Lottie file takes much space and cannot be aligned properly with a circle image when there are multiple XML components in the UI.
So, I want to know if we have any other ways to create the example 2 UI.

Comment: This is one of the most challenging aspects of Android development.You won't find any tutorial about this. You can try using a custom view with a progress bar or create custom drawings

Comment: Custom drawing? What is that can you tell me??

Comment: These can't be designed in XML. Use gif or short videos for this. You can use multiple videos or GIFs for different stages.

Comment: I mean Painting App and like @TariqMahmood said, example you showed, it can't created by XML

Comment: Thank you for your response, I think I understand it a little bit after doing some research on custom drawing and using GIFs.

Answer (score 0):

These can't be designed in XML. Use gif or short videos for this. You can use multiple videos or GIFs for different stages.